# Resolve errors in project files after merge

Tags: xcode, git, merge, xcode-project

I merged my code and got some conflicting files, I resolved the merge conflicts but still get the "Workspace integrity/ Couldn't load project" error. The error is probably in the project file but there are no conflicts in the file. What's the best approach to solving this error? Is there a tool to analyze if something is wrong in the project file?

Comment: Did you commit after resolving conflicts? i.e. is the merge concluded?

Comment: No not yet, but is it a good idea if I can't even start the project?

Comment: What does `git status` show you from the Git bash?  Did you already add and/or commit these files?

Comment: Dunno about xcode, but for sure doing a commit is no harm and can be undone

Comment: @Francesco Ok, I will give it a try

Comment: @Francesco I didn't fix it, but I didn't pushed it yet, because i don't like to push something which is broken

Comment: Do a `git diff` or `git diff --staged` and check the diffs, see what sticks out.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen  Doesn't show anything but I already commited it

Comment: OK, then do a `git diff HEAD~1 HEAD` and look at that then, but if your project is corrupt, why did you commit?

Comment: I did that, because Francesco told me so. However I didn't pushed it yet.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So my develop branch is still working and i haven't pushed my changes to the master yet. So would it be a good idea to just get the local master to the newest version and try the merge again?